# visualize monthly input and output (flow) rates in a Google Sheet chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, cumulative-sum, google-sheets-charts

I have a sheet with ticket data - one ticket in each row. Each ticket has an opened date. When a ticket is closed it gets a closed date.

Looking at a month view we have:

- **input rate** = how many new tickets are opened each month
- **output rate** = how many tickets are closed each month
- **open tickets** = how many tickets are/were open each month

I'll use this as example data:

```
| opened date | opened month | closed date | closed month |
|:-----------:|:------------:|:-----------:|:------------:|
|  2019-04-03 |    2019-04   |             |              |
|  2019-03-12 |    2019-03   |             |              |
|  2019-03-09 |    2019-03   |             |              |
|  2019-02-12 |    2019-02   |  2019-03-06 |    2019-03   |
|  2019-01-06 |    2019-01   |  2019-05-09 |    2019-05   |
|  2019-01-09 |    2019-01   |             |              |
|  2019-01-12 |    2019-01   |             |              |
|  2019-03-09 |    2019-03   |  2019-04-09 |    2019-04   |
|  2019-02-09 |    2019-02   |             |              |
|  2019-04-12 |    2019-04   |  2019-06-12 |    2019-06   |
|  2019-02-12 |    2019-02   |             |              |
|  2019-04-03 |    2019-04   |  2019-07-09 |    2019-07   |
|  2019-01-12 |    2019-01   |  2019-03-03 |    2019-03   |
|  2019-03-09 |    2019-03   |  2019-05-12 |    2019-05   |
|  2019-04-12 |    2019-04   |             |              |
|  2019-03-12 |    2019-03   |             |              |
|  2019-04-03 |    2019-04   |  2019-07-09 |    2019-07   |
|  2019-03-12 |    2019-03   |  2019-07-03 |    2019-07   |
|  2019-01-09 |    2019-01   |             |              |
|  2019-01-09 |    2019-01   |  2019-05-09 |    2019-05   |
|  2019-02-12 |    2019-02   |             |              |
|  2019-03-09 |    2019-03   |  2019-06-06 |    2019-06   |
|  2019-04-03 |    2019-04   |  2019-05-09 |    2019-05   |
|  2019-04-03 |    2019-04   |             |              |
|  2019-02-03 |    2019-02   |             |              |
|  2019-04-03 |    2019-04   |  2019-06-03 |    2019-06   |
|  2019-03-12 |    2019-03   |             |              |
|  2019-01-03 |    2019-01   |  2019-02-06 |    2019-02   |
```

If I **manually** combine the opened dates, with the closed dates, I get this:

```
|  month  |  type  |
|:-------:|:------:|
| 2019-01 | opened |
| 2019-01 | opened |
| 2019-01 | opened |
| 2019-01 | opened |
| 2019-01 | opened |
| 2019-01 | opened |
| 2019-01 | opened |
| 2019-02 | opened |
| 2019-02 | opened |
| 2019-02 | opened |
| 2019-02 | opened |
| 2019-02 | opened |
| 2019-02 | closed |
| 2019-03 | opened |
| 2019-03 | opened |
| 2019-03 | opened |
| 2019-03 | opened |
| 2019-03 | opened |
| 2019-03 | opened |
| 2019-03 | opened |
| 2019-03 | opened |
| 2019-03 | closed |
| 2019-04 | opened |
| 2019-04 | opened |
| 2019-04 | opened |
| 2019-04 | opened |
| 2019-04 | opened |
| 2019-04 | opened |
| 2019-04 | opened |
| 2019-04 | opened |
| 2019-05 | closed |
| 2019-05 | closed |
| 2019-05 | closed |
| 2019-05 | closed |
| 2019-05 | closed |
| 2019-05 | closed |
| 2019-06 | closed |
| 2019-06 | closed |
| 2019-06 | closed |
| 2019-06 | closed |
| 2019-06 | closed |
| 2019-08 | closed |
```

I can put this in a pivot to get:

```
|  month  | closed | opened |
|:-------:|:------:|:------:|
| 2019-01 |        |    7   |
| 2019-02 |    1   |    5   |
| 2019-03 |    1   |    8   |
| 2019-04 |        |    8   |
| 2019-05 |    6   |        |
| 2019-06 |    5   |        |
| 2019-08 |    1   |        |
```

This shows me how many were opened and closed each month. I can use this as the source for a chart:

[image]

But this doesn't show how many were open each month - a running total of new opens, plus old opens, minus closed. If I do the math manually I get:

```
|  month  | closed | opened | open |
|:-------:|:------:|:------:|:----:|
| 2019-01 |        |    7   |   7  |
| 2019-02 |    1   |    5   |  11  |
| 2019-03 |    1   |    8   |  18  |
| 2019-04 |        |    8   |  26  |
| 2019-05 |    6   |        |  20  |
| 2019-06 |    5   |        |  15  |
| 2019-08 |    1   |        |  14  |
```

[image]

So, I am wondering if there is a way to take my source data and generate the pivot table/chart I am after automatically - showing how many opened per month, closed per month, and how many are open each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this double running total:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 IF(A2:A, MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(C2:C)<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(C2:C)))*C2:C), SIGN(C2:C)), IFERROR(1/0))-
 IF(A2:A, MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B2:B)<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B)))*B2:B), SIGN(B2:B)), IFERROR(1/0)), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(QUERY(IF({B2:B; D2:D}<>"", {B2:B&"♦opened"; D2:D&"♦closed"}, ), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0), "♦"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2 format Col1'yyyy-mm'", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({""; IF(F3:F<>"", 
 IF(F3:F<>"", MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(H3:H)<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(H3:H)))*H3:H), SIGN(H3:H)), IFERROR(1/0))-
 IF(F3:F<>"", MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(G3:G)<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(G3:G)))*G3:G), SIGN(G3:G)), IFERROR(1/0)), )})
```

[image: 4]

Comment: This requires me to manually take the original data (first table in my question) and join the two sets of dates (the second table in my question). I'm looking to avoid that. And have it spit out the final end table with the totals too...

Comment: I'll create one and share from home. Can't do from work. Will do it tonight.